# Sorting two layers array by underscore .sortBy or javascript .sort function

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have problem with JSON sorting by increase. Now it looked:

```
var array = {
   "2014\/2015":{
    "gamesPlayed":17,"goals":2,"assists":8,"points":10
   },
   "2013\/2014":{
    "gamesPlayed":52,"goals":18,"assists":16,"points":34
   },
   "2012\/2013":{
    "gamesPlayed":39,"goals":12,"assists":15,"points":27
   }
};
```

I need to sort item by year and get objects like this 2012/2013:{...}, 2013/2014:{...}, 2014/2015:{...}
I try to sort it by:

```
var sorted = array.sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b;
});
```

but it show misstake in console.

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` variable is really an `object`, that has no `.sort()` method, since the keys are unordered.

Comment: use a real array @stress_tn

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your 'array' object into a real array, first get the date values and sort them:

```
var date, realArrayOfDates = [];
for (date in array){
    realArrayOfDates.push(date);
}
```

then sort `realArrayOfDates` using `sort():

```
realArrayOfDates.sort();
```

Now you can iterate over the sorted dates and pull items out of 'array' in order

```
var realArrayOfObjects = [];
for (i in realArrayOfDates) {
    realArrayOfObjects.push(array[realArrayOfDates[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this with underscore or lodash. This add a `year` property on each item of your object, converts it to an array, and then sorts the array.

```
_.chain(array)
 .map(function(val, key) {
   return _.extend({year: key}, val);
 })
 .sortBy('year')
 .value();
```